# How to get the background color of a canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

What I am trying to do is this:
Using Fabricjs, I wish to `alert("the bg color is: "+canvas.getBackgroundColor())` however, that method does not exist.

I also tried `canvas.backgroundColor` but that returns an empty string.

Despite my efforts, nothing seems to return the background color of a canvas. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html canvas is transparent by default.

When an empty canvas is drawn, the body's background will be visible.

To set the background color in fabricJS, do this:

```
canvas.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

As long as you have already set the background color, you can retrieve it like this:

```
var bkColor = canvas.backgroundColor;
```

Alternatively, you can set the background in CSS because the canvas that fabricJS creates will take the CSS of the canvas element you initially supply:

```
#myCanvas{ background-color:"skyblue"; }
```

Comment: I want fabricjs to return the canvas color. I set it to red. I click a button then I want it to give the color of the background in an alert.

Comment: No problem.  Assuming you have set the background color so it's not null, you can retrieve it using canvas.backgroundColor (backgroundColor is a property of fabric.canvas)

Comment: That keeps on returning an empty string when called automatically, but it does work if I wait a second or two before calling it. Thanks!